# Intermittent, unexpected FIN & RST problems

Tags: networking, tcp

When working in a cloud application, the server intermittently issues FIN and then RST. For example, the user of the app performs a function (say choosing a value in a field) that works fine, and then performs the same action and gets FIN and then RST in response, when it shouldn't.  What kinds of issues could be causing this behavior?  (Sorry I don't have the rep to post the pcap from Wireshark.)

Answer (score 0):

The FIN means the server application closed the connection and results in an EOS condition at the client, whereupon the client should close its end too. There's nothing 'unexpected' about that. The RST could have a number of causes, but if you are detecting EOS correctly at the client the RST should be of no consequence whatever.

Comment: Thanks. By "unexpected", I mean that the user working in the application is not expecting the connection to close, but rather to have their chosen action (selecting a value in a field) work.  Instead, the server seems to close the connection.  To your point though, there is no EOS recorded; the server sends FIN, ACK and the client tries to post, at which point the server sends RST.

Comment: So the question here is why is the server application closing the connection. Given that it has done that, sending an RST when receiving further data is not to be expected.